# segment-line intersection algorithm why sort by end point

Tags: algorithm

I am working on algorithm given a set of `n` segments `{(a0, b0), (a1,b1), (a2, b2)...(an-1, bn-1) }`. Here we have found the minimum number `m` of points such that each segment contains at least one point.

Here I sorted data from first coordinate i.e., an in ascending order and compare the `b` coordinate is in the range of current end range as shown below.
If I use lhs.end <= rhs.end algorithm works, but if is use lhs.start <= rhs.start algorithm fails

```
struct Segment {
    std::uint64_t start, end;
  friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &out, const Segment &c);
};

bool operator < (Segment lhs, Segment rhs) {

    if(lhs.end <= rhs.end) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}


    std::sort(segments.begin(), segments.end());
std::uint64_t uiPresentSegStart = segments[0].start;
std::uint64_t uiPresentSegEnd   = segments[0].end;
std::uint64_t uiPresentIdxStart = 0;
std::uint64_t uiTotalSegments = 1;
for (size_t i = 1; i < segments.size(); ++i) {
    if(segments[i].start <=  uiPresentSegEnd) {
        continue;
    }
    uiTotalSegments++;
    uiPresentSegEnd = segments[i].end;    
}
```

But this algorithm is not working. When I looked at the algorithm it was told that I have to sort by `b` coordinate. I am not getting why we have to sort by `b` coordinate? Can anyone give one example why sorting on first coordinate algorithm fails?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the segment intersection algorithm using a sweep line to compute intersections. In this algorithm, we should specify the event points. The event points in sweep line (from left to right) would be endpoints of the segments (you can see it in the algorithm). Hence, you should sort all endpoints as event points of sweep line to move on them (all start and endpoints).

In sum, sorting by endpoints help the algorithm to know, where the segment-line is finished and will not compute the finished segment line in intersection computation after passing the segment line's endpoints.

Comment: I got we should sort by end points but why to sort by end points and not by start points

Comment: @venkysmarty sorting by endpoints help the algorithm to know, where the segment-line is finished and will not compute the finished segment line in intersection computation after passing the segment line's endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for explanation but still I didn't get why sorting by start point fails

Comment: @venkysmarty because if you don't know the endpoints order, the algortihm deos not know which segments are finished and this can be buggy.

Comment: if I go other way if I know where is start point then we can work through that way right.  Sorry I still didn't get it By the way I added code and edited question for clarity. Any example where sorting by start point fails will be helpful

Comment: @venkysmarty As I said, you should sort all start and endpoints altogether. As event points should be traced by the seep line in a sorted order. Hence, we need traverse all start and endpoints in a sorted order to find that when a segment is started and when a segment is ended.